# Process suspends when run asynchronously

Tags: terminal, sudo, background-process, stdin

I have process I'd like to start, and forget about. When run synchronously, it looks like

`sudo -E lein run`

This runs fine, indefinitely. It is non-interactive. It starts a web server at port 80. But when I run:

`sudo -E lein run &`

The terminal outputs:

`[4] 30236`

and a few seconds later:

`[4]  + 30236 suspended (tty input)  sudo -E ../bin/lein run`

and my process, which should start a web server at port 80, doesn't show a server.

Questions:
How do I diagnose what's going on? I don't think standard out and standard error are being printed, but I could be wrong. Why does the process suspend? Can I get `lein run` to run asynchronously another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [why do I get “Suspended (tty output)” in one terminal but not in others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056102/why-do-i-get-suspended-tty-output-in-one-terminal-but-not-in-others).

Comment: This is similar to my question, but the accepted answer to that question doesn't work for me. I get the same behavior after running `stty -tostop`. And, as a side-note, it doesn't answer the question why does OP get "suspended (tty output" in one terminal but not in others?

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command expects to be able to talk with a user via a tty. When you push it into the background it stops because it's expecting exclusive access to the tty but no longer has exclusive access. (It's a security interface, which might require a password, and certainly runs a program with different access rights to the user account. It's important it has exclusive access to the user.)

You can run your program under `screen`, which gives it a virtual tty that is not necessarily associated with a "real" tty.

```
screen -md sudo -E lein run
```

Answer (score 1):

Background processes can't read from the terminal. If they try, they get suspended by a SIGTTIN (**t**ele**t**ype **in**put) signal. The reason for this feature is that if more than one process was trying to read from the terminal, each character would go essentially randomly to one of the processes, which is not useful behavior. Thus the foreground process gets the input and the background processes don't.

(I simplified a little. Read about [controlling terminals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_03) and [terminal access control](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_04) if you want a more precise specification, but you'll rarely encounter scenarios where you need to dig deeper than what I wrote above.)

If sudo tries to read from the terminal, to prompt for your password, it gets suspended. You need to run sudo in the foreground, and then switch to the background.

In general you can run a shell and then tell it to execute a command in the background. For example, with `su`, you'd do `su -c 'lein run &'`. But the authors of sudo know that this is a common problem, so there's an option for that: **pass the `-b` option to `sudo`**.

```
sudo -b -E lein run
```

Similarly with `ssh` you can use `-f` to go into the background after prompting for a password. Note that if you do that, your background process will not be a shell job. If you want to run the program in the background and forget about it, that's perfect.